# Can you reset/retrieve a username/password used in schema creation of a desktop Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have an Oracle 12C desktop database schema I created some time ago.  I don't remember the username/password for when I created the schema.

Is there any way to retrieve it?  I have full admin privileges for computer.

Thanks much.

Comment: Simple and short answer: Not possible! That's the purpose of credentials. You can give only a new password to the user.

Comment: Didn't you try to authenticate by using `sys / as sysdba` from the command line of the OS of the server where you've installed the DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login as `SYS` (I suppose you are still able to do that) and then issue:

```
alter user <<schema>> identified by <<new_password>>;
```